# React JSX - inject br tag in loop

Tags: reactjs, loops, jsx

How can I add a 
 tag between selected options in jsx?

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
  id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
  multiple
  value={preferences}
  onChange={handleChangePreferences}
  input={<Input />}
  renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(<br />)}
  // MenuProps={MenuProps}
  style={{width: "100%",  whiteSpace: "break-spaces"}}
>
```

I've tried br , \n, "\n" - i can't find a way that works.

The Material UI [docs](https://material-ui.com/components/selects/#multiple-select) show an example with a comma - I'm trying to use a br

Answer (score 0):

Update the `Select` component to this. E.g https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-40jg3

```
<Select
  labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
  id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
  multiple
  value={personName}
  onChange={handleChange}
  input={<Input />}
  renderValue={selected => (
    <>
      {selected.map(value => (
        <>
          {value}
          <br />
        </>
      ))}
    </>
  )}
  MenuProps={MenuProps}
>
```

Comment: Your suggestion formats results inside a select box. I'm trying to print them out in a render statement, joined by a br tag. do you know how to achieve that? –

Comment: @Mel Updated the comment above.